# Rename overlapping methods, added by observable, without affecting the others

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There's an `ActiveRecord` model, which has it's own (basically, included from the other ActiveRecord's module) `#changed?` and `#change` methods. And there's a module `Observable` which also has it's own `changed?` and `change` definitions.

I need to define a custom module, which automatically includes `Observable` module and performs some underlying logic, but the problem is, that when I try to `alias` and `undef` original `Observable` method, it also `undefs` methods from other modules, which is critical.

Is there any elegant way to solve this? As I don't really want to implemet a custom `Observable` module.

Here's an example code:

```
require 'observer'

# Trying to undef Observable's #changed and #changed?
# But really, when included, it also undefs methods from
# other modules included by original class
module TryingToRewriteChanged
  include ::Observable

  alias triggerable_changed? changed?
  alias triggerable_changed changed

  undef_method :changed?
  undef_method :changed
end

# Custom module which has some logic in .included
module Triggerable
  def self.included(obj)
    obj.class_eval do
      include TryingToRewriteChanged
      # ... And other magic
    end
  end
end

# Mock for some ActiveRecord module with 
# #changed and #changed? definitions
module ActiveRecord
  module SomeActiveRecordModule
    def changed
      puts 'original changed'
    end

    def changed?
      puts 'original changed?'
    end
  end
end

# Mock for ActiveRecord::Base class
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    include SomeActiveRecordModule
  end
end

# Example model, which need to include Triggerable module
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Triggerable
end

# ActiveRecord's #changed is no more available
SomeModel.new.changed
# -> undefined method `changed'
```

https://repl.it/repls/KeyQuickwittedAsiantrumpetfish

Thank you.

Comment: You may want check this http://blog.jayfields.com/2007/08/ruby-calling-methods-of-specific.html

Answer (score 1):

It you try to print ancestors of model, it will show

```
SomeModel.ancestors # [SomeModel, TryingToRewriteChanged, Observable, Triggerable, ActiveRecord::Base, ActiveRecord::SomeActiveRecordModule, Object, JSON::Ext::Generator::GeneratorMethods::Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Hence, when calling `SomeModel.new.changed`, it will call `changed` of `Observable`. And this method already `undef_method`, it will throw exception as the document: https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/undef_method

> Prevents the current class from responding to calls to the named
>   method. Contrast this with remove_method, which deletes the method
>   from the particular class; Ruby will still search superclasses and
>   mixed-in modules for a possible receiver.

There is 2 way you can use to resolve this issue:

1 - Prepend `ActiveRecord::SomeActiveRecordModule` before `TryingToRewriteChanged` in inheritance chain.

```
# Mock for ActiveRecord::Base class
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    include Triggerable
    include SomeActiveRecordModule
  end
end

# Example model, which need to include Triggerable module
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

ref: https://repl.it/repls/ProudGuiltyMorpho

But using this way, you have to accept that `Triggerable` will be included in all ActiveRecord subclasses which may larger scope than your expectation.

2 - Implement `changed` and `changed?` methods in `SomeModel` to call corresponding methods in `SomeActiveRecordModule` explicitly. Using some techniques of metaprogramming may help to shorten the code.

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Triggerable

  def changed
    ActiveRecord::SomeActiveRecordModule.instance_method('changed').bind(self).call
  end

  def changed?
    ActiveRecord::SomeActiveRecordModule.instance_method('changed?').bind(self).call
  end
end
```

ref: https://repl.it/repls/ContentTameIsabellinewheatear

Comment: Thank you @Tai, but it will mean leaving the abstraction and hardcoding ActiveRecord modules, but it will be better to keep the logic as abstract as possible. I found solution how to solve the problem, but it's pretty ugly, will post it in a few minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Found pretty ugly but working solution, the main magic happens under the `TryingToRewriteChanged` module:

```
require 'observer'

# Create aliases for #changed and changed? methods from 
# Observable - basically, renaming them.
# And then call top-level methods of the first includer when
# receiving #changed / changed?
module TryingToRewriteChanged
  include ::Observable

  alias triggable_changed changed
  alias triggable_changed? changed?

  [:changed, :changed].each do |method|
    define_method(method) do |*args|
      return super(*args) unless origin_method_present?(method)
      call_origin_method(method, *args)
    end
  end

  private

  def call_origin_method(name, *args)
    method(name).super_method.super_method.call(*args)
  end

  def origin_method_present?(name)
    method(name).super_method&.super_method&.name == name
  end
end

# Custom module which has some logic in .included
module Triggerable
  def self.included(obj)
    obj.class_eval do
      include TryingToRewriteChanged
    end
  end
end

# Mock for some ActiveRecord module with 
# #changed and changed? definitions
module ActiveRecord
  module SomeActiveRecordModule
    def changed
      puts 'original changed'
    end

    def changed?
      puts 'original changed?'
    end
  end
end

# Mock for ActiveRecord::Base class
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
    include SomeActiveRecordModule
  end
end

# Example model, which need to include Triggerable module
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Triggerable
end

# ActiveRecord's #changed is no more available
SomeModel.new.changed
```

https://repl.it/repls/ThirstyFlawedXanthareel